# Grouping in ItemsControl using ItemsSource from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, grouping, itemscontrol, itemssource

I've defined `ItemsControl` like that:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SellingDashboardToDosList}"
              BorderThickness="1" Background="#C7E8F8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ToDoList}">
    <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=Model.TodoType}" >
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </GroupBox>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `ItemsSource` is a `SynchronisedObservableCollection<T>` in the `ViewModel`. But this XAML doesn't produce any grouping. I assume that I should specify somehow that `ItemsSource` is groupable. But where should I specify it?

If I would use an `XmlDataProvider` with some static data, then I could do it in a `CollectionViewSource` element like in following example: http://cromwellhaus.com/2010/03/grouping-is-crazy-easy-in-wpf/ ([Archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20160602204708/http://cromwellhaus.com/2010/03/grouping-is-crazy-easy-in-wpf/)).

I've tried to do it like that:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionViewSource1" Source="{Binding Path=ToDoList}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="TodoType"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

But then I get a runtime binding error:

> Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.;
>   Value='System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView'
>   BindingExpression:Path=ToDoList;  DataItem='ToDosViewModel'
>   (HashCode=40956219);  target element is 'CollectionViewSource'
>   (HashCode=51380674);  target property is 'Source' (type 'Object');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used ListCollectionView in C# instead of CollectionViewSource in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

> But then I get a runtime binding error that ItemsSource is of invalid type.

Did you reference it correctly? You need to specify it as `Binding.Source`:

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSource1}}"
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with how CollectionViewSource is binded in ItemsControl. Please take a look at the question again: I've updated the error message.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400: The message seems to suggest that you already have a view in your ViewModel, you could easily adjust your binding or your VM to account for this.

Comment: Never mind, the problem is solved. Thank you for your willingness to help.